# how to extract specific range of characters from string with casting to array type-- What it can't be done?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, casting

I have this code

```
char *c="hello";
char *x=malloc(sizeof(char)*5+1);
memcpy(x,(char[2])c,sizeof("hello")+1);
x[5]='\0';
printf("%s\n",x);
```

it gives error that cast specifies array type.  why is that? what's the reason behind this error. Does this mean `I can't cast like with array type meaning:I can cast to pointer like (char *) but I can't cast to array type like (char[2]) or (char[])` Am I missing anything?

What I need to do in my code to resolve the error cast specified array type error at

```
 10 |         memcpy(x,(char[2])c,sizeof("hello")+1);
```

Comment: `x` is a pointer to an array of six characters, with indexes from `0` to `5`. `x[6]` is out of bounds.

Comment: As for your problem, what is the purpose of the cast in `(char[2])c`? What are you trying to accomplish with that? What is the problem it's supposed to solve? What is your expected result of the `memcpy` call?

Comment: Even if you fix the cast and treat `c` like an array of two characters, it will just decay back to a pointer, and the cast won't magically have inserted a null terminator. Try saying exactly what you want to achieve, rather than focus on fixing the compile error on a line that's never going to do what you want anyway.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `As for your problem, what is the purpose of the cast in (char[2])c?` I just like to see casting is working or not? why its not working?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have corrected it

Comment: @Useless `cast won't magically have inserted a null terminator.` yes I know I just want to see cast works or not

Comment: The cast doesn't work, that's what the compiler is telling you. But why are you doing that cast?

Comment: `sizeof("hello")` is valid? I would have done `strlen("hello")`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I like to extract first two letters from c in one line

Comment: `strncpy(x, c, 2); x[2] = '\0';`?

Comment: So the correct way to do that is by passing `2` as the size parameter (instead of `sizeof("hello")+1` which you *know* is not the size you want)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude so u are saying casting to array type is wrong

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Literals strings like `"hello"` are really arrays of characters (including null-terminator). So `sizeof` works and returns the size of the array itself (which will include the null-terminator, unlike `strlen`). This also means that `sizeof("hello") + 1` is too much to copy and will copy one extra character out of bounds.

Comment: Yes. The compiler is telling you it's wrong, and I've told you it wouldn't do what you want anyway. You can look at the definition of [`memcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy) and see that its second parameter is a pointer. The size information is passed explicitly as the third parameter, so just put the correct value there.

Comment: thanks all understood

Comment: you cannot cast a pointer to an array. But you **can** cast it to a pointer to array. Try `(char*[2])c`

Comment: @tstanisl `(char*[2]) c`   is c is pointer to array of two char? Can u please tell me this

Comment: @user786, sorry, it should be `(char(*)[2])c`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays do not have the assignment operator. You may not write for example

```
char *c="hello";

char s[6];

s = c;
```

As a result such a casting like

```
( char[6] )c
```

is not allowed.