# if array type does not have = operator then I understand that but why my casting of pointer/array to pointer to array is working not as expected

Tags: c

why this code does not seem to work the way I expect

```
    char *c="hello";
    char *x=malloc(sizeof(char)*5+1);
    memcpy(x,(char(*)[2])c,sizeof("hello"));

    printf("%s\n",x);
```

On this question I got comment `you cannot cast a pointer to an array. But you can cast it to a pointer to array. Try (char*[2])c` so I am just casting to pointer to array of two char so it will get first two characters from c becuase this is what `(char(*)[2])c` suppose to do. If not then am I missing anything? and I thought since Iam copying it the at index after 1 and 2 I get junk because i did not call memset. why I am getting full `hello` write with memcpy even though I just casted it t0 `(char(*)[2])`

[how to extract specific range of characters from string with casting to array type-- What it can't be done?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70004229/how-to-extract-specific-range-of-characters-from-string-with-casting-to-array-ty?noredirect=1#comment123750862_70004229)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591624/understanding-the-source-code-of-memcpy sorry just had to see the implementation of memcpy

Comment: I'm curious, what do you think `sizeof("hello")` will return?

Comment: @paddy including null terminator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Converting a pointer does not change the memory the pointer points to. Converting the `c` to `char [2]` or `char (*)[2]` will not separate two characters from `c`.

`c` is `char *` that points to the first character of `"hello"`.

`(char (*)[2]) c` says to take that address and convert it to the type “pointer to an array of 2 `char`”. The result points to the same address as before; it just has a different type. (There are some technical C semantic issues involved in type conversions and aliasing, but I will not discuss those in this answer.)

`memcpy(x,(char(*)[2])c,sizeof("hello"));` passes that address to `memcpy`. Due to the declaration of `memcpy`, that address is automatically converted to `const void *`. So the type is irrelevant (barring the technical issues mentioned above); whether you pass the original `c` or the converted `(char (*)[2]) c`, the result is a `const void *` to the same address.

`sizeof "hello"` is 6, because `"hello"` creates an array that contains six characters, including the terminating null character. So `memcpy` copies six bytes from `"hello"` into `x`.

Then `x[5]='\0';` is redundant because the null character is already there.

To copy `n` characters from position `p` in a string, use `memcpy(x, c + p, n);`. In this case, you will need to manually append a null character if it is not included in the `n` characters. You may also need to guard against going beyond the end of the string pointed to by `c`.

Comment: Demo: `printf("%p %p\n", (void*)c, (void*)(char(*)[2])c);`

Comment: thanks for answer. is it doable to implement own memcpy do I need to recompile libc?

Comment: @user786: Certainly one can implement their own `memcpy`, but it is part of standard C and is already present in the C library in normal implementations.

Comment: If you're asking if there's a way to change the definition of `memcpy` so it works the way you expected it to (i.e. only copying two characters when the source pointer's type is `char (*)[2]`, even if the size argument is larger) then the answer is no. The C language cannot do that. (It *might* be possible in C++ with a template function but I don't know how to do it.)

Comment: I don't know why you don't just use `strncpy`.  That seems to do exactly what you want, minus the syntax hacks.